# Google Places Search Dynamic Data Loading

Tags: google-maps, web, web-scraping, google-places

Hi am trying to search Google Places and the basic structure is fine:
https://plus.google.com/local/Leeds,%20United%20Kingdom/s/car%20rental

But for loading additional data you scroll down the page. I have used fiddler to check the request but cannot identify where any of the data being posted comes from?

Does anyone know how to simply load or start on page 2/3. Or even load moare than 10 at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will load from 30 to 40, it respons in a format that I can't recognize, but it does what you want. You must be more specific if you want further assistance. Offset is the offset of the query, so 30 gets from 30 to 40, 100 gets from 100 to 110 etc.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

import requests

url = "https://plus.google.com/_/local/searchresultsonly"

offset = "30"

data = {
    "f.req": '[[[],[],"car rental","Leeds, United Kingdom",[],["Leeds, West Yorkshire, UK",[0,0,0,0]],null,0],[{}]]'.format(offset),
}

print requests.post(url, data).text
```

Comment: Thanks. I follow most of that. I write in c#. I cant quite figure out what data ends up as in this format?
Is it just a string or - Im note sure. 
Can you confirm what that post data would look like once submitted.

Comment: Never mind, I got it now. Thanks. Its working.
And by the way, the response is JSON data.

Comment: Ohh, my parser could not recognize it as json, but glad you got it working.

Comment: I just need to trim off 4(ish) characters off the front of it and its fine :P